# How to convert a full length date with time to just date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a date that is retrieved when the user clicks on a specific date from a calendar widget. 
For example, if the user was to press 29th march the program outputs:

```
2017-03-29 00:00:00
```

When I want

```
2017-03-29
```

How do I fix it so I can use it with SQLite (same form as second example).

```
    def datefunction(self,agro):
        print(agro)
        timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = (?)''',(agro,))
        print('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = (?)''',(agro,))
        list1 = list(cursor.fetchall())
        print(list1)
        if list1== ([]):
            print("You have nothing on today.")

    def _show_selection(self, text, bbox):
        """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
        agro = self.selection
        print(self.selection, self.datefunction(agro))
        print(agro)
```

result I get from code:

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = (?) (datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 29, 0, 0),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

you could explicitly request only the date part in the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = date(?)
```

here, the [`date`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function automatically extracts the corresponding date from its input.

or as suggested by @Shuo, pre-format the date manually using

```
agro.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and feeding this into the query:

```
dstr = agro.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = (?)''',(dstr,))
```

Comment: when putting in the split function I get this error: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: agro.strftime('%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: @pythonsnake sorry, I thought for a while that `agro` is a string

Comment: @Shuo where should I put that in? I tried multiple places and it didn't work.

Comment: @ewcz sorry, should have been more specific.

Comment: try this agro[:10]